# one folder for dropbox in linux and windows

Tags: linux, windows, dropbox

I have a dual boot Windows XP / Linux mint system. I created a partition to share data between Windows XP and Linux, and there I would like to have the (shared) Dropbox folder. How can I achieve that? setting this location for Dropbox on the first system is no problem, but setting it on the 2nd results in an error: there's already a Dropbox folder on this location and something like that.

Is there a way to have Windows XP and Linux have the exact same location for the Dropbox folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I used to be able to do so:
install dropbox in one OS. Set the default dropbox directory.
After that, Dropbox starts syncing files.

Then, shut down this OS and boot into the other.
Empty the dropbox directory. Then Install dropbox and again, set the default dropbox directory.
Dropbox starts syncing again. 
After that, both OS's have the same dropbox directory.

Comment: I did this but somewhere along the line dropbox got confused and started nesting itself between reboots. Probably because it auto-appended `/Dropbox` to the selected folder. Quickly ran out of space. I like the idea but it has some risk :P